# Negative Margins For RecyclerView Item Decoration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, margin, item-decoration

I need to implement the below layout for my `RecyclerView` Items (The picture represents two rows):

[image]

This is my `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/theme_primary_color">

    <View
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/half_circle"
        android:translationZ="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cvTop"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cvTop" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_green"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cvTop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvTop" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to set negative margins to root `ConstraintLayout` but the second item went to top of the first one, but I need the first item to be on top of the second one.

Comment: Both items represent a single row?

Comment: No. Each item is placed in a separate row

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a good design idea, regardless of how you achieve it the view boundaries will overlap which will create issue with touch events (mapped to wrong positions on the overlapping area)

Comment: Is there no bug-free solution?

Comment: instead of adding half circle view, take customise card which has half circle in middle or take rectangle view with half circle in middle

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Do you have an example?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali: No, I don't but if you are able to share rectangle image with half circle in middle then may be I can create new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is not exactly what you want but at least it has the same layout as you want with a simpler approach.

So, the main challenges are:

- Taking a curve cutout on the `CardView` probably need to be built programmatically with canvas for a better result. But for simplicity, this is replaced by a `BottomAppBar` wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout` in order to have the curve effect with the top circle/gap.
- Replacing the top `View` with `Fab` in order to have an **Inset FAB** by setting the `layout_anchor` to the `BottomAppBar`. [Check  material design for this](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom).

  And having the cutout behavior requires to make the FAB like it doesn't exist by setting a transparent `backgroundTint` & removing the `outlineProvider`
- Making the top cutout (gap) of a particular row get overlapped to the top row like if it is a part of it. This works with the negative margin on the root view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cvTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:outlineProvider="none"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/navigation" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cvTop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvTop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Item No. 0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: you can remove the `TextView`, I just added it to check the item doesn't change its position like you had in your case.

Preview on the `RecyclerView`

[image]

**UPDATE:**

A new challenge:

- Only the top half of the `FAB` will intercept touch events, as any particular row will be laid on top of its direct top row; and hence the `FAB` of the top row won't intercept events in the intersection area.

  Well, this can be manipulated well using canvas & custom View.
  But also this can be solved in the current approach by laying out the rows of the `RecyclerViews` from bottom to top.
  One way to [`setReverseLayout(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#setReverseLayout(boolean)) and then either:

  => Reverse the `RecyclerView` list positions before submitting to the adapter

  => Or use `mList.size - 1 - position` instead of `position` within the adapter. Assuming the list of items is `mList`

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity, did you face any challenge with touch event handling? specifically on the bottom of FAB my initial assumption was that it might require a custom view that's aware of its clip bounds to consume or pass touch input events cmiiw

Comment: @rahul.taicho Most probably that need to be handled in the intersected bottom area of the FAB, I will test it

Comment: @rahul.taicho you're right for the events are intercepted on the top non-intersected part, but not in the bottom part.. there is a workaround that I am working on to resolve this.

Comment: @rahul.taicho Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Woah! The reverse layout technique is pretty neat TIL

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the general *RecyclerView* layout looks and operates OK except that each item view overlays part of the item view above such that the bottom part of the top view's FAB cannot be seen.

I believe that what you are seeing is a result of the top-down default drawing order of *RecyclerView*. To change the drawing order to bottom-up so the bottom-most view overlays the one above, take a look at [RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback) to see if you can get a reverse drawing order that will work.

Try the following:

```
mRecycler.setChildDrawingOrderCallback(new RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback() {
    @Override
    public int onGetChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
        return childCount - i - 1;
    }
});
```

I am not sure how you are offsetting your items, but consider using an [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration). Something like this:

```
class OverlapItemDecoration(context: Context, overlapDp: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    private val overlapPx: Int

    init {
        overlapPx = (context.resources.displayMetrics.density * overlapDp.toFloat()).toInt()
    }

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) return
        outRect.set(0, overlapPx, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Both of these techniques, together, will create a *RecyclerView* with overlapping item views laid out bottom to top so the FAB is 100% clickable.

Here is an example of the application of these techniques. I also replaced the *CardView* with a *MaterialCardView* with a *ShapeableImageView* as a background.

[image]